# How to do rolling regression against multiple independent variables using the roll_lm function

Tags: r

I'm trying to regress returns against FF 3-factors with a rolling window.

To do so, I have found the function roll_lm in R, but the function is only producing regression output for one of the 3 variables.

The code is described here:

```
 Y <- as.matrix(Portfolio_returns[,2])
    X1 <- as.matrix(Mydata[,2])
    X2 <- as.matrix(Mydata[,3])
    X3 <- as.matrix(Mydata[,4])

Five_years_Rolling_reg <- roll_lm(X1 + X2 + X3,Y,60)
```

When I apply the coef function, I only get output for X1 and not X2 nor X3.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You problem seems to be a basic misunderstanding of how the function works. Looking at `?roll_lm`

> Arguments
>
> **x**
>   matrix or xts object. Rows are observations and columns are the independent variables.

Currently it seems like you are trying to use a `formula = X1 + X2 + X3` style of input, which is not what the help page is saying. As such it is adding the columns together as if it was: `x1 = 2; x2 = 3; x1 + x2 = 5`

Instead you should bind the rows together.

```
Y <- as.matrix(Portfolio_returns[,2])
X <- as.matrix(Mydata[,2:4]
roll_lm(X, Y, 60)
```

Or alternatively use the `model.frame`, `model.response`, `model.matrix` functions from `base`-R, which gives you the familiarity of the formula settings.

```
names(Mydata)[1:4] <- c("Y", "X1", "X2", "X3")
frame <- model.frame(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = Mydata)
X <- model.matrix(Y ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data = Mydata)
roll_lm(X, model.response(frame), 60)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Your corrections helped a lot!

Comment: No worries. Please mark this as answering the question, in order to help others more easily find it in the future. :-)